# What are groups on the same z-coordinate called? (eg, such groups on the same x-coord are called "columns".)

Tags: naming

I am wondering if there is a conventional name for groups that lie on the same z-coordinate. Eg, such groups on the same x-coord are called "columns", and such groups on the same y-coord are called "rows". Is there such a conventional name for groups that lie on the same z-coord? Thanks! [ :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean "layer"?

It is also used in photoshop